# Unable to mount fastboot boot twrp.img backup unable to mount storage?

Tags: twrp, encryption, mount

I was trying to load  fastboot boot twrp.img and  take backup of stock rom system.img userdata.img through twrp recovery...

it loaded successfully but  while taking backup its  not able to take backup its  giving error that it "**cant mount storage**" its  not  able to select  sdcard microsdcard  and internal memory to showing 0 free space

is there any  way to  mount  and show  the internal memory or external sd card in twrp recovery image  any suggestions

My mobile device have

> OS Android 6.0.1 Marshellow Processor Qualcomm Family cortex a53
> Machine arrch 64 Architecture arm cortex a53 External memory card 64GB
> ROM 16 GB MOBILE NOT ROOTED

thank for your suggestion time and advice

Comment: @alecx bro thank for replying comments  is there any way younsughest to solve this encryption by yourself how to write to keep maintenance ...Can we infuse some mounting script in twrprecovery.img by yourself I found ways but not worked anyone can solve encryption problem links for ways.   https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/how-to-fix-unable-to-mount-data-internal-storage-0mb-in-twrp-permanently.3830897/.             https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-twrp-unable-to-mount-storage-internal-storage-0mb/

Comment: @alecx bro thank a lot here is the link    https://dl.twrp.me/mobee01a/twrp-3.5.2_9-0-mobee01a.img.html

Comment: according to last [commit](https://github.com/TeamWin/android_device_LYF_mobee01a/commit/f6d9c85#diff-dbe3492) encryption is already fixed. please share */tmp/recovery.log* via pastebin.com

Comment: @alecxs bro if commit encryption is already there in this step image then why mount error is coming is it for encryption or any problem how to solve problem

Comment: @alecxs bro 
The below links funded in Google shows that this error is due to encryption of mobile device files tried following option to decrypt but not worked either problem with two recovery image

https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/...rnal-storage-0mb-in-twrp-permanently.3830897/

https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-twrp-unable-to-mount-storage-internal-storage-0mb/

Comment: please share /tmp/recovery.log via pastebin.com. without recovery.log i can not help